# How to build two WordPress site using two different themes with same database (No ! I am not taking about multisite network)?

Tags: functions

I want build two WordPress site using two different themes with same database (No ! I am not taking about  multisite network)?

- Site one : example.com
- Site two : second.example.com

Both sites information are 100% same but **internal links are different because of site_url is differ**, but I will use two themes. How can I do this?

---

**Why I need this?** I want to build a android app for my WordPress site. What I do is I just load my website using [Android WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). I use `second.example.com` for build the android app because I need different layout and want to change the navigation bars, etc...

Comment: you can change the table prefixes for both installations

Comment: Then, how happen data sync part. When I adding a post to example.com, how it store to second.example.com.

Comment: basically to run two themes you'd need 2 databases. Also on the data part, you can have same content for posts/pages but not the same URL as they're on different domains. This might help https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195208/sync-posts-from-one-wordpress-site-to-another